# Changing in hosts file

Tags: iis-7.5, hosts

I have configured my website from VS2010 to use IIS 7.5. Then I added this line to my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 something.com
```

This correctly goes to IIS 7.5 default screen

However I want this to go to my website that is hosted in IIS 7.5. So I changed the above line to:

```
127.0.0.1/MyWebSiteHostedinIIS something.com
```

But when I did this it stopped working. Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how can I correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hosts` file only maps domains to IP addresses. It does not handle "virtual folder" mappings.

You should leave your original line intact:

```
127.0.0.1 something.com
```

In IIS, right-click your site, choose `Edit Bindings...`, click `Add`, and under `Host name` type *something.com*.

Comment: I think Edit Bindings won't help. I want that when someone types something.com. It should go to something.com/MyWebSiteHostedinIIS

Comment: Your site is a virtual directory or a real root site?

Comment: So you must access it via its virtual folder... no way to bypass it. Anyway, I highly recommend you to run on a root site; there's no reason to use virtual directories. It's out of scope to discuss it thoroughly, but the bottom line is that there's nothing good in sites that are virtual. Only headaches.

Comment: :D Ok. Thanks Ofer. I will listen to your sane advise and work on root site itself.